# Laptop recognizes WiFi, gets no signal

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, laptop, iwlwifi

I installed Ubuntu on my laptop, and after multiple attempts to install a stable version, it finally worked. However, I face issues with receiving and sending data over any network. Portable hotspot and home networks do not send or receive data. I do connect to those networks with no issue, however. I have spent hours trying to find a working solution, but I haven't found any. Please do **NOT** use any solutions with direct access to databases, for my laptop cannot use these.

TL:DR - Laptop had several issues with installation, successful installation cannot send or receive data over network.

Laptop: HP 8470p Elitebook

EDIT: WiFi card is Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 (3x AGN if it helps), and the Wireless LAN is not hard or soft blocked.
It also seems that I do not have the interface files, and then it proceeds to fail when trying to open /run/network/ifstate
EDIT 2: Logs are in pastebins for reasons
https://pastebin.com/rmFhv2q6
https://pastebin.com/Ln3Lynzp

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: You can't find a solution if you don't know your wireless device.

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Please add the precise output and also `dmesg | grep iwl`. You can connect the laptop using USB tethering to your phone.

Comment: I don't happen to have a cable right now, so I guess I'll have to wait till I get home. I will also try what you suggested.